# Como adicionar o Account no projeto Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core

Sou novato no asp.net core mvc e estou tendo uma dificuldade, tenho um projeto que no visual studio tenho uma solução para 4 projetos diferentes.
Digamos que seja apenas o projeto A e projeto B.
O projeto A seria o site antigo da empresa e o projeto B seria um novo sistema, por padrão no projeto A veio a configuração de account conforme a imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já o projeto B não veio o account conforme a imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso utilizar o account para meu novo projeto(B)?

OBS: Esse projeto A seria deletado futuramente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No projeto B, você está utilizando a versão mais nova do ASP.NET Core Identity que já traz a parte de autenticação em funcionamento, e então você pode customizar de acordo com sua necessidade, porém de uma forma diferente do que estavamos acostumados na versão anterior.

Você pode especificar no momento da criação do projeto, ou então adicionar posteriormente.

Na criação do projeto, você deve clicar em "Change Authentication" e selecionar "Individual User Accounts".

[image: Criação do projeto]

Depois você clique em cima do seu projeto e vá Add -> New Scaffolded Item -> Selecione Identity e clique e clique em Identity.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sugiro que você leia a documentação oficial do [ASP.NET Core Identity](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio), existem vários cursos abordando o assunto na internet.

Comment: Samuel perfeita explicação muito obrigado.